Modeling magnetometer for attitude estimation
I am trying to model a magnetometer for attitude estimation of a CubeSat. I am confused on whether to use my estimated position from GPS or my true position from dynamics when calculating my magnetic field. The reference magnetic field is in the ECI frame and I need my measurement in the body frame. Do I transform this vector using the estimated attitude or truth attitude from dynamics. How will my kalman filter implementation look like?

Is this for use in the cubesat flight computer software? If so, the software will have access only to the GPS the and not the true data; right? Please [edit] your question to include where the computations will occur. Off line (ground) or online (cubesat).

Your dynamics model does not yield "truth". It instead yields an approximation of "truth", an approximation whose error from "truth" grows over time.


I am confused on whether to use my estimated position from GPS or my true position from dynamics when calculating my magnetic field.

If you are using a GPS receiver that works in spaceflight (most receivers have firmware that prevent use in space, and some can't even handle the speeds involved) then you plug those coordinates into your algorithm that calculates the Earth's field at that point in space.
If your GPS is returning valid data, it's by far the most accurate you're going to get in a cubesat.
There's not likely any "dynamics" calculation implementable inside a cubesat from say an inertial guidance system that will give you better positional information for calculating Earth's field at that point.
